# Plotting values from numpy array in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a numpy array `X` that has

```
[[-2.26188258  0.83339356]
 [-2.04141033  0.84618611]
 [-2.09993514  0.97093103]
 [-2.22863577  0.70044229]
 [-1.98995538  1.04537757]
 [-1.98696162  0.81267152]
 [-2.14523421  0.92106693]]
```

I want to use `pyplot.plot` to use the first element of each item as `x` and the second element as `y` to plot a scatter plot.

```
xval = [x[0] for x in X]
yval = [x[1] for x in X]
ax.plot(x = xval, y = yval, marker = 'o', linestyle = 'None', color = dbclrs[i + 1])
```

this is what I tried, but it gives me an empty plot. I am trying not to use the `scatter` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [call signature of `plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) is

```
plot(*args,*kwargs)
```

Hence you need to call

```
ax.plot(xval, yval, marker = 'o', ...)
```

---

Also note that if `X` is your array you can directly plot

```
ax.plot(X[:,0],X[:,1], ...)
```